# "Network Scalability" : Scalabilité du Réseau ? Ou Extensibilité du Réseau ?

Tags: terminologie, informatique, science

Quel est le meilleur équivalent français du terme suivant en informatique ?

- **Network Scalability:**
- **Scalabilité du Réseau ?** Ou **Extensibilité du Réseau ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux vont très bien.

- **scalabilité** devrait plutôt être utilisé avec un public connaisseur
- **extensibilité** a l'avantage de ne pas être un anglicisme

Je me permets de proposer encore une autre traduction:

- **capacité à monter en charge/montée en charge** Pour moi c'est celui qui illustre le mieux le concept, mais il est assez lourd à utiliser.

Comment: De façon similaire, on peut dire *capacité d'évolution*. J'aime pas trop evolutivité, scalabilité ou extensibilité qui appartiennent au jargon informatique.

Comment: @Graffito Oui, si on parle d'un réseau de revendeurs par exemple, mais le contexte de la question est clairement celui de l'informatique. Je n'y ai jamais entendu ou dit autre chose que *scalabilité du réseau*.

Comment: Si la scalabilité (horizontale ou verticale) est bien une façon de répondre à un besoin de montée en charge, on peut pas dire que l'un soit l'équivalent (ou la traduction de l'autre). Pour ma part j'avais pensé à "capacité de mise à l'échelle", "évolutivité" ou encore "dimensionnabilité".

Comment: J'aime bien l'idée de _dimensionnement_ ici.

Comment: @jiliagre : En dehors d'informaticiens familiers du déploiemnt de solutions informatiques, peu de gens connaissent ou peuvent définir le terme de scalabilité.

Comment: @Graffito Peu de gens, en effet. Il s'agit encore d'un mot de jargon. On commence à le rencontrer ailleurs, comme en [économie](https://www.usine-digitale.fr/article/au-fait-c-est-quoi-un-modele-economique-scalable.N395152).

Answer (score 1):

> *extensibilité, variabilité dimensionnelle, variabilité d'échelle,
> évolutivité* ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&index=ent&srchtxt=scalability))

Évidemment, avec « réseau » soit on fait des adjectifs, et c'est plus difficile avec les termes en deux mots (*à échelle/dimension variable*) ou on emploie les termes avec la détermination par « réseau » (*du/d'un réseau*).

Comment: Ce n'est rien d'autre que _échelle/dimension_ avec ce qui se module d'après ce critère ou et s'y conforme ou a le potentiel d'être de cette nature. On a aussi plus généralement _souplesse_, qui peut s'adapter, s'échelonner etc. On peut disserter là-dessus, mais rarement avec un seul mot c'est tout.